# Fourier transform of an inverse function.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, integral-transforms

If for a given function $f(x)$, the Fourier transform is $\hat{f}(p)$; Is there a way to find the Fourier transform of $f(x)^{-1}$ in terms of $\hat{f}(p)$?

Comment: The title asks about the "inverse function", which is $f^{-1}(x)$. In the post you ask about $f(x)^{-1}$, which is the reciprocal, not the inverse function. So it's hard to know what you mean. Luckily the answer is the same for both: No.

Comment: i did indeed ask about the reciprocal. There was a recent paper(arXiv:1010.5060v1) where the authors have done this for Mellin transform, e.g, if the mellin transform of $f(x)=\sum_n a_n x^n$ is $M[f(x)]=F(u)$ then the mellin transform of $1/f(x)$ is $M[1/f(x)]=F(u)\Gamma(u)\Gamma(n-u)$. That's why i was curious....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: There are some facts known about it. For example, the Wiener algebra is closed under taking reciprocals. (Fourier series)

Comment: A solution to this would solve: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283778/given-product-and-convolution-of-pair-of-functions-can-you-find-original-pair

Comment: What is $n$ in $M[1/f(x)]=F(u)\Gamma(u)\Gamma(n-u)$? Is there really a sum over $n$ in this result?