# How to simultaneously remove a convolution and a multiplication

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, functional-equations, functional-calculus

If you have an equation of the form

$$ a(x) \star f(x) + b(x)f(x)=0 $$

Where $\star$ is convolution over the real line and $a,b$ are given functions where you want to solve for the set of possible $f$.

Is there some way to express $f$ as an operator-equation in terms of $a,b$? The standard intuition of taking a fourier transform doesn't work here since it reduces one convolution to multiplication and transforms the other multiplication into a convolution.

This feels like a fundamental operation that should exist and among other things a discrete variant of it would help resolve [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458313/solving-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-prime-counting-function?noredirect=1#comment1187323_458313).

Superficially it also appears to be related to [the pauli problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283778/given-product-and-convolution-of-pair-of-functions-can-you-find-original-pair/4288263#4288263)

Comment: Thanks for your question!

Comment: $f = 0$ is always a solution. If you are looking for non-trivial solutions, $f$ is never unique since multiplying $f$ by a constant gives another solution.

Comment: Ah yes, given this is a homogenous linear equation that makes sense. I am interested in the set of non trivial solutions and/or generating just one non trivial solution

Comment: "The standard intuition of taking a fourier transform doesn't work here since it reduces one convolution to multiplication and transforms the other multiplication into a convolution." Just throwing out odd ideas, but would a (1/2) Fractional Fourier Transform get both A-F and B-F terms into the same kind of half-convolved-half-multiplied situation?

Comment: Hmm that is a very interesting idea!

Comment: You can compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768288/is-there-a-function-whose-autoconvolution-is-its-square-g2x-gg-x